# Flutter/Firebase - Right Track?

Tags: firebase, flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

At 54 I'm self-learning Flutter and have come a long way. I am stuck (again) with a speed-bump concerning my implementation of Firebase. Although I am getting the very basic of displaying a line of data for each record the problem is getting to the details of each record. I believe the issue is that I am not referencing the record ID.

When looking at endless examples I also believe my code to display a ListView of records is bloated making it more difficult to grab a record and display all fields (edit screen).

I want to click the "Walsh-Test" links to view all fields and update. I can create a new edit/update screen my initial problem is opening the screen to the selected record.[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class MeterReadHomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff4367b1),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text(
          "WelakaOne",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('meter_reads')
            .orderBy('accountname')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 20, 0, 0),
            child: Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.docs.map(
                    (document) {
                      return Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            width: 50,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.access_alarm,
                              size: 36,
                              color: Color(0xff4367b1),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Text(
                              document['accountname'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xff4367b1),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 44),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
[![Flutter/Firebase/Open to Selected Record][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want to go to another page (Edit Screen) onTapping the alarm tile.
So, my suggestion is to use A ListTile widget instead of the row widget you are using.

You can read about ListTile's onTap property, [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/onTap.html)
Regarding your routing to a new screen/page, you'll have to make use of MaterialPageRoute to create a new route and using Navigator's push method you can push it onto your Material App.

Attaching an example code that uses Navigator to go to different pages, you need the BuildContext of your app. Here is an example of how you can get it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rate_your_professor/screens/firstScreen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Some App',
      home: SomeApp(),
    );
  }
}

class SomeApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget getListView(BuildContext context) {
    var listView = ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.location_city),
          title: Text("XXXXX ", textDirection: TextDirection.rtl),
          subtitle: Text(
            "XXXXXXXXXX",
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          ),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => YourNewPage(),
                  ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
    return listView;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: getListView(context));
  }
}
```

Comment: Tharun, Thank you for the info and example. Unfortunately I am still working towards a solution. I will continue to learn how to make your example fit my into my code and research this subject. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: you are just missing a ListTile and it's onTap property which must have MaterialPageRoute, just go through my example, it isn't very hard. Hope you get this soon!